# After training a GPT model with Keras, how to load it and provide a custom text prompt to generate an output?

Tags: keras, nlp

I am following the tutorial for [GPT text generation from scratch with KerasNLP](https://keras.io/examples/generative/text_generation_gpt/) ([src code](https://github.com/keras-team/keras-io/blob/master/examples/generative/text_generation_gpt.py)).

How can I save this generated model, then in another script load it and provide a custom text prompt to it to generate an output?

Following on from the source code above, I am saving the code like so:

```py
import os
output_dir = "keras_model_output"
if not os.path.exists(output_dir):
    os.mkdir(output_dir)
model.save(output_dir+"/output.h5")
```

Now in another script I'd like to load this trained model and then use it and provide a text prompt. This is what I have tried, but it results in an error:

```py
from tensorflow import keras
import keras_nlp
output_dir = "keras_model_output"
perplexity = keras_nlp.metrics.Perplexity(from_logits=True, mask_token_id=0)
model = keras.models.load_model(output_dir+"/output.h5", custom_objects={'perplexity_loss': perplexity})
model.summary()

model.predict(["This is a text prompt"])  # What do I do here?
```

The error stacktrace is:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/mendhak/Projects/train-gpt2-tutorial/4.keras.predict.py", line 8, in <module>
    model.predict(["This is a text prompt"])
  File "/home/mendhak/miniconda3/envs/tf/lib/python3.9/site-packages/keras/utils/traceback_utils.py", line 70, in error_handler
    raise e.with_traceback(filtered_tb) from None
  File "/tmp/__autograph_generated_filew9rnc7p4.py", line 15, in tf__predict_function
    retval_ = ag__.converted_call(ag__.ld(step_function), (ag__.ld(self), ag__.ld(iterator)), None, fscope)
  File "/tmp/__autograph_generated_file6hn_k2m7.py", line 73, in tf__call
    decoder_mask = ag__.converted_call(ag__.ld(merge_padding_and_attention_mask), (ag__.ld(decoder_sequence), ag__.ld(decoder_padding_mask), ag__.ld(decoder_attention_mask)), None, fscope)
  File "/tmp/__autograph_generated_fileansctahb.py", line 70, in tf__merge_padding_and_attention_mask
    ag__.if_stmt(ag__.ld(mask) is not None, if_body_2, else_body_2, get_state_2, set_state_2, ('mask',), 1)
  File "/tmp/__autograph_generated_fileansctahb.py", line 65, in if_body_2
    mask = ag__.converted_call(ag__.ld(tf).cast, (ag__.ld(mask)[:, ag__.ld(tf).newaxis, :],), dict(dtype=ag__.ld(tf).int32), fscope)
ValueError: in user code:

    File "/home/mendhak/miniconda3/envs/tf/lib/python3.9/site-packages/keras/engine/training.py", line 2169, in predict_function  *
        return step_function(self, iterator)
    File "/home/mendhak/miniconda3/envs/tf/lib/python3.9/site-packages/keras/engine/training.py", line 2155, in step_function  **
        outputs = model.distribute_strategy.run(run_step, args=(data,))
    File "/home/mendhak/miniconda3/envs/tf/lib/python3.9/site-packages/keras/engine/training.py", line 2143, in run_step  **
        outputs = model.predict_step(data)
    File "/home/mendhak/miniconda3/envs/tf/lib/python3.9/site-packages/keras/engine/training.py", line 2111, in predict_step
        return self(x, training=False)
    File "/home/mendhak/miniconda3/envs/tf/lib/python3.9/site-packages/keras/utils/traceback_utils.py", line 70, in error_handler
        raise e.with_traceback(filtered_tb) from None
    File "/tmp/__autograph_generated_file6hn_k2m7.py", line 73, in tf__call
        decoder_mask = ag__.converted_call(ag__.ld(merge_padding_and_attention_mask), (ag__.ld(decoder_sequence), ag__.ld(decoder_padding_mask), ag__.ld(decoder_attention_mask)), None, fscope)
    File "/tmp/__autograph_generated_fileansctahb.py", line 70, in tf__merge_padding_and_attention_mask
        ag__.if_stmt(ag__.ld(mask) is not None, if_body_2, else_body_2, get_state_2, set_state_2, ('mask',), 1)
    File "/tmp/__autograph_generated_fileansctahb.py", line 65, in if_body_2
        mask = ag__.converted_call(ag__.ld(tf).cast, (ag__.ld(mask)[:, ag__.ld(tf).newaxis, :],), dict(dtype=ag__.ld(tf).int32), fscope)

    ValueError: Exception encountered when calling layer 'transformer_decoder' (type TransformerDecoder).
    
    in user code:
    
        File "/home/mendhak/miniconda3/envs/tf/lib/python3.9/site-packages/keras_nlp/layers/transformer_decoder.py", line 264, in call  *
            decoder_mask = merge_padding_and_attention_mask(
        File "/home/mendhak/miniconda3/envs/tf/lib/python3.9/site-packages/keras_nlp/layers/transformer_layer_utils.py", line 70, in merge_padding_and_attention_mask  *
            mask = tf.cast(mask[:, tf.newaxis, :], dtype=tf.int32)
    
        ValueError: Index out of range using input dim 1; input has only 1 dims for '{{node model/transformer_decoder/strided_slice_5}} = StridedSlice[Index=DT_INT32, T=DT_BOOL, begin_mask=5, ellipsis_mask=0, end_mask=5, new_axis_mask=2, shrink_axis_mask=0](model/token_and_position_embedding/NotEqual, model/transformer_decoder/strided_slice_5/stack, model/transformer_decoder/strided_slice_5/stack_1, model/transformer_decoder/strided_slice_5/stack_2)' with input shapes: [?], [3], [3], [3] and with computed input tensors: input[3] = <1 1 1>.
    
    
    Call arguments received by layer 'transformer_decoder' (type TransformerDecoder):
      • decoder_sequence=tf.Tensor(shape=(None, 256), dtype=float32)
      • encoder_sequence=None
      • decoder_padding_mask=None
      • decoder_attention_mask=None
      • encoder_padding_mask=None
      • encoder_attention_mask=None
```